# Node Lambda does not fail even though DDB key doesn't exist and return null as result instead

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda

I'm wondering if anyone can help me troubleshoot my Node lambda. I have a DDB with key of user and visit_count, but when I am calling getCommand with wrong key parameter, the lambda is allowing it with success test & resulted in null. Does anyone know what I'm missing?

```
// Instrument the AWS SDK client
const client = tracer.captureAWSv3Client(new DynamoDBClient());

//const client = new DynamoDBClient({});
const dynamodb = DynamoDBDocumentClient.from(client);
const table_name = process.env.TABLE_NAME;

const lambdaHandler = async (event, context) => {
    let body;
    let statusCode = 200;
    
    const user = event.user;
    let visit_count = 0;
    
    try {
        const params = {
            TableName: table_name,
            Key: {
                user: user
            }
        };
        
        body = await dynamodb.send(new GetCommand(params));
        if (body.Item) {
            visit_count = body.Item.visit_count;
        }
        visit_count++;
        
        const putParams = {
            TableName: table_name,
            Item: {
                user: user,
                visit_count: visit_count
            }
        };

        body = await dynamodb.send(new PutCommand(putParams));
    
        const message = `Hello ${user}! You have visited us ${visit_count} times.`;
        console.log(message);
        return {
            message: message
        };
    
    }catch (err) {
        statusCode = 400;
        body = err.message;
    } finally {
        body = JSON.stringify(body);
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You lambda will only shortcut to the `catch` section if an exception happens within the `try` block.

An otherwise valid `GetItem` request to a DynamoDB table or index that does not result in a match will not result in an HTTP error. It will return a 200 status with a valid (albeit empty) JSON object for the response (modulo supplementary data).

From the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_GetItem.html#API_GetItem_Examples):

> The `GetItem` operation returns a set of attributes for the item with the given primary key. If there is no matching item, `GetItem` does not return any data and there will be no `Item` element in the response.

A 200 response from DynamoDB won't reject the promise returned by `dynamodb.send`, and awaiting for it won't trigger an exception.

If a non-match is an exceptional situation as far as your logic is concerned, you should check the response and throw the exception manually if `Item` is not returned:

```
if (!body.Item) {
  throw new Error("User not found"); // or similar
}
```

Note that even when exceptions do happen inside your function, Lambda (the runtime) has no way of knowing that because the function is not communicating that. You have a global try...catch block that effectively swallows all the errors. You are assigning values to local variables `status` and `body`, but not returning them or doing anything meaningful with them.

If you want to tell Lambda that your function failed, you need to reject the promise your handler returns. The easiest way to do that is to remove your try...catch block altogether, throw an exception when something irrecoverable happens, and let nature take its course.

The variables `status` and `body` (that you apparently blindly copy-pasted from some example on the internet) will only translate to an HTTP status code and an HTTP response if you're using your Lambda as a [proxy integration](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/set-up-lambda-proxy-integrations.html) for API Gateway. You'll have to actually return them from your handler for it to work. Even if you do that and the status will be a 4** or 5** value, it will still count as success from Lambda's perspective.

Comment: This doesn't work. I'm trying to find out what's being thrown out, but even debug logs won't show the console.log() result. https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/introducing-advanced-logging-controls-for-aws-lambda-functions/. Any idea how to debug this null?

Comment: I'm actually getting closer to the finish line (https://pastebin.com/ufuQHjKn) following this async handler docs (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/nodejs-handler.html#nodejs-handler-async). Somehow it's resulting in success even though logs is showing error. Screenshots: https://imgur.com/a/W7gzuC3

Comment: @AlphaK12: your function, unless it times out, will always fulfil the promise it returns, because you're catching all the exceptions that can possibly happen in your code and swallowing them. From the Lambda's point of view, it's a success.